# php JavaBridge vs Zend Java Bridge configuration

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

We started using Zend Java Bridge, but periodically run into errors like "class not found" after new builds and other config issues because of ZJB running its own layer, as well as passing problems with zeroes to floats at times. We had already switched from Quercus due to bugs we experienced.

Now we are looking at the php Java Bridge located at:
http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

This appears to have the benefit of connecting directly to Tomcat.

The native one to php is out, as we are running php5.

Because this is such a limited scope, (questions remain unanswered about this on the zend forums)

My question is: for those of you that have tried either one (or both), which has been found to be less problematic coding-wise and configuration wise?  I really don't know where else to ask this.

The correct answer will be whatever explanation or experience that is the most helpful.

Thank you in advance. Your answers may prevent making a ton of changes to existing code.

Comment: Added my thoughts after working with them both for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration-wise, I'd say php Java Bridge wins. There's no middle jvm, and Tomcat does the work instead. Therefore, no weird incompatibility, and no no throwing special exceptions in the java code.

Code-wise on the php side, I'd say Zend Java Bridge wins. The internal error messages are better, and don't just die sometimes with no error messages like php Java Bridge.

Speed has not been an issue at all with either platform, even with doing large queries.

Answer (score 0):

I once was looking for a 'java bridge' to communicate from php as well, I searched all over stackoverflow and I kept running into user experiences saying that it just performed too slow (php-java-bridge). That may be just because of the fact that it's a bridge between 2 platforms.

note: I never went through with my php->java idea so I never tried it.